# Wifi adapter detected but doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, wifi, driver

I started my Raspberry Pi 2, connected to an external monitor. Everything works as supposed.

I connected my [USB Wifi adapter](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/300M-USB-Wifi-Micro-Adapter-Dongle-Plug-and-Play-for-Raspberry-Pi-2-B-RTL8192CU/32376026954.html) and it's being detected by the pi:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 04: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
...
```

However, there are no wifi networks:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions

eth0      no wireless extensions
```

Realizing I don't have Internet connection on the raspberry, how can I make the wifi connection work?

I'm running [`Raspbian`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/). So, how can I make it work (maybe some missing packages?)?

---

Relevant output:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


auto wlan0
allow hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "..."
        wpa-psk "..."
$ uname -r
3.18.13-v7+
$ ls /lib/modules/3.18.13-v7+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
at76c50x-usb.ko  brcm80211    mac80211_hwsim.ko  rt2x00     zd1211rw
ath              hostap       mwifiex            rtl818x
b43              libertas     p54                rtl8192cu
b43legacy        libertas_tf  rndis_wlan.ko      zd1201.ko
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
# wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "Edimax"
        wpa-psk "<password>"


auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Can you provide any `dmesg` logs that describe what wifi adapter is detected? I'm wondering if the kernel is recognizing the USB ID and loading any modules.

Comment: @WineSoaked [Sure!](https://gist.github.com/IonicaBizau/6dd3c15dc69e0a9b17ce) I don't think would be a good idea to post it here in the question... :-) I connected an ethernet cable to make my life easier and I'm connected from my laptop via ssh to raspberry.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the adapter is being enumerated, but no driver is being loaded for it. So... the short version of this is that you might need to get a different wifi adapter, one that is guaranteed to run on the version of Raspbian (or whatever OS you've chosen).

Comment: The somewhat longer option would be to locate a driver that will recognize that USB ID and make sure that it's available on the SD card. This is not a beginner-level task.

Comment: @WineSoaked But... I have a CD with the drivers. And it contains an install script. I tried it and it compiles some C/C++ stuff and then fails: `recipe for target 'modules' failed`.

Comment: The drivers on the CD may not compile to an ARM target architecture. You would have to transfer all of the files over to the Pi and then run the install script from there, unless the CD includes a cross-compiler. I haven't done it myself, so I don't have direct experience with this adapter.

Comment: @WineSoaked Actually, I'm getting the same error on a pc running Ubuntu...

Comment: What is your kernel version (`uname -r`)? What is output of `ls /lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/`?

Comment: @DavidLechner I added the output in the question body.

Comment: `rtl8192cu` in the output of `ls /lib/modules/3.18.13-v7+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/` tells me that that out have the correct driver. Not sure why it is not loading though. Perhaps it is blacklisted? You could try running `sudo modprobe 8192cu`.

Comment: @DavidLechner Probably that helps too–I had to run something related for starting the sound. But I think the problem is in the configuration too (I appended it into the question). When I run `sudo ifup wlan0` I get some errors: `Cannot find device "wlan0" Bind socket to interface: No such device Failed to bring up wlan0`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidLechner So, any idea why this error appears?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: there really is no "wlan0" device. There is no "wlan0" device because the driver is not loading.

Comment: @DavidLechner But is the configuration correct (see the question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther reason why you don't have a wlan0 is that you don't have a wlan0 stanza in your `/etc/network/interfaces`. Go there and make a setting for wlan0 by typing
`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and add the example stanza

```
auto wlan0
allow hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "ssidofyourrouter"
        wpa-psk "passwordofyourrouter"
```

If you have auto line, allow line is not compulsory, for more information check https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

`iface wlan0 inet dhcp` isn't your only option, you can set it manual or static too but the settings will be different. After you added the stanza I've put above to `/etc/network/interfaces`type `sudo ifdown wlan0` and then `sudo ifup wlan0`.

If you have entered the right settings you will be connected to the router you have been specified in the stanza by "ssidofyourrouter" and "passwordofyourrouter". By dhcp(dynamic host configuration protocol) then your Pi will be assigned an IP between the specified interval in your router settings.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting `misplaced option` on `allow hotplug wlan0` line.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you edit your question with your settings in /etc/network/interfaces and also with error

Comment: How to install `iwdown`? Previously I tried on another computer. On raspberry I get `-bash: iwdown: command not found`.

Comment: Commands are ifdown, and ifup :)

Comment: Ah, true! :) I updated my question. The error is `/etc/network/interfaces:19: interface wlan0 declared allow-auto twice`, which makes sense I guess.

Comment: If I merge them, the error is again `misplaced option`.

Comment: Just delete one of the stanzas, I would delete 2nd one, and instead of "..."s type your ssid and password so you can connect to an actual modem, delete or comment out >>>auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf <<< Then you'll be good to ifup and ifdown without error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26842/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-tolga-varol).

Comment: Can we give it another try? I switched on Raspbian and updated my question with the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting `sudo ifup wlan0 I get some errors: Cannot find device "wlan0" Bind socket to interface: No such device Failed to bring up wlan0` when `sudo ifup wlan0`

Comment: I think the cause of error is that wifi dongle isn't seen or identified by RPi so it might be a firmware issue @IonicăBizău , I don't have my Pi with me for a while and I won't have any other Linux distro with me to check stuff for a week or two

Comment: I bought [another adapter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36640/33613) and `iwconfig` was listing it. :) Just added the `wpa-ssid` and `wpa-psk` rows and voila, I have internet. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :) @IonicăBizău

Answer (score -1):

The NOOBS kernel does not have a driver for this USB device. Try using the Raspbian image instead.

Ref: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/issues/50#issuecomment-129484228

Comment: I am currently using Raspbian actually. I'm going to give you a bounty if you solve my issue... :)

Comment: See [my comment](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34278/wifi-adapter-detected-but-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment49105_34278).